# How do we define the sum of a bi-infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, definition

If we have a (usual) series of the form
$S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$
then we define $S$ to be the limit as $N$ goes to infinity of the partial sums $S_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n,$
provided the limit exists. If we instead have a bi-infinite series of the form
$$
S = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n
$$
then how do we define this sum? Is it
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=-N}^N a_n
$$
or
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} \lim_{M \to \infty} \sum_{n = -M}^N a_n
$$
or something else? Can you also refer me to any standard textbook that deals with bi-infinite series? Thanks!

Comment: The latter (the limit as $N$ and $M$ go to infinity).

Comment: @Did Can I interchange the limits without any problems?

Comment: There is no interchange here. One asks that: $$\forall\epsilon>0\quad\exists N\quad\exists M\quad\forall n\geqslant N\quad\forall m\geqslant M\quad\left|\sum_{k=-n}^ma_k-L\right|\leqslant\epsilon$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure the definitions are different and that there are examples that converge with the first and not the second. No time now to look for one but if I'm right someone will provide and answer soon.I'd guess that the second one is "standard".

Comment: Try $\sum \frac1n$. One definition converges to a finite value, the other does not. $\sum \text{sign}(n)$ is another example.

Comment: Thank you! Can you also suggest any book that I could read that discusses bi-infinite series in particular?

Comment: @Did I don't think that this is how it is usually defined. Any reference?

Comment: @Did just FYI, this is not copied and I don't even remember whether I read about this particularly in Tao's book. The sum over $\Bbb N$ is the integral with respect to the counting measure - from this point of view, it makes sense to define the sum over an arbitrary set as the integral with respect to the counting measure. This is the content of my answer (integration theory aside).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bi-infinite summation is summation over $\Bbb Z$. In general (I think that I read about this in Professor Tao's Analysis book), one defines a sum over an arbitrary set $X$ as follows.

Let $X$ be any set and $F(X)$ be the set of all finite subsets of $X$. Let $f: X \to \Bbb R$ be nonnegative.

$$\sum_{x \in X} f(x) := \sup\{\sum_{x \in A} f(x): A \in F(X)\}$$

Now if $f$ is not necessarily nonnegative, then in case $\sum_{x \in X} |f(x)|$ is finite,

$$\sum_{x \in X} f(x) := \sum_{x \in X} f^+(x) - \sum_{x \in X} f^-(x)$$

Where $f^+(x)= \max\{f(x), 0\}$ and $f^-(x) = \max\{-f(x), 0\}$.

Otherwise $\sum_{x \in X} f(x)$ is undefined.

In the case $X = \Bbb Z$, it's easy to check that when $\sum_{x \in \Bbb Z} f(x)$ is defined, we have that the limit:

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=-N}^N f(n)$$

exists and equals that thing.

Comment: In this method, we choose to define the sum of a bi-infinite series only when it is absolutely convergent. This is too restrictive.

Comment: In fact, the sum of even a standard infinite series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n$ is defined only for absolutely convergent series, by the above method.

Comment: @Brahadeesh sums over $\Bbb N$ are another matter. I'm not an expert (hence my asking Did), so you can't take my word for it - this is my understanding of how an "abstract sum" may be defined. I think that Did's definition is more useful.